# ESB 4.9.0 removes all QoS configuration

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I try to set Throttling on service, and this configuration in 4.9.0 is not available anymore.

Why this features was removed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

QoS features have been removed from Carbon kernel 4.4.0. You can use WSO2 Developer studio to implement the QoS feature and deploy in the ESB 4.9.0